# GCM Server Side Run-time Error (NoClassDefFoundError : Message$Builder )

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

This is the server side code for GCM notification, i have build this successfully on ubuntu using command line by adding gcm-server.jar,  but at run time it crashes with exception.  I have added the jar in the classpath.

```
  Exception at run time :  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android  /gcm/server/Message$Builder  
    at geo.sendNotification.sendNow(sendNotification.java:30)  
    at geo.geosense.main(geosense.java:27)  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   com.google.android.gcm.server.Message$Builder  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)  
..
```

.

```
import org.json.simple.*;  
import java.util.*;  
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message.Builder;  
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;  
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;  
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;  
public class sendNotification {  
Sender sender = null;  
public void sendNotification ()  // function to send message   
    {  
Sender sender = new Sender("XYZ"); // api key      
    }  
    public void sendNow(String deviceID, String msg, String param)  
    {  

    Message message = new Message.Builder()  
                    .addData("message", msg)  
                    .addData("parameter one", param)  
                    .build();  
    try{      
    Result result = sender.send(message, deviceID, 1);  
    }  
    catch ( Exception e )  
    {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }      
    }}  

____________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

`NoClassDefFoundError` means that the application is unable to find the location of the file inside the Application's folder. It is advised to keep all the library files and jar files in `libs` folder of the project.

Make sure that you have put the gcm.jar file inside the `libs` folder and not `lib` folder.

To do that go to `project properties` > `java build path` > `order and export` then give a tick on the jar file that you have added.

Here's a related SO ticket which discuss about `NoClassDefFoundError`: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23675699/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-gcm-googlecloudmessaging)

Comment: I am building the application on linux using command line. All jars are in the lib folder. I have also renamed to libs but no access. The application builds successfully but crahes with NoClassDefFoundError exception