# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, google-maps-api-2, android-multidex

Using Maps api v2 and it works perfectly with 4.4 , 5.0, 5.1, 5.1.1 , 6 but app crashes when I try 4.2.2. I've been doing lots of research but nothing seems to work. Here's the complete log.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.
         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzk$zza.get(
         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzc.zzkG(
         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzr.<init>(
         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzb(
         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.<init>(
         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx.zzBQ(
         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzaU(
         at com.google.android.gms.measurement.ource)
         at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider
         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.
         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any ideas?

Here´s my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "py.com.roshka.billeterabancard"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.glomadrian:loadingballs:1.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.5.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.3'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.3'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share inside build.gradle of your app please? there may be a hint :)

Comment: @dgngulcan there it is!

Comment: please try adding apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' in your outer scope @passerin

Comment: Not sure if it's related but I was getting a similar error after upgrading to AndroidX and the fix was to upgrade my `com.google.android.gms:play-services` dependencies from `11.8` to `17.0`. Hopefully that helps others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research and hours of testing I finally realized that android has something called the DEX 64K Methods Limit. In simple words there's a limit you can reach when adding external libraries to your project. When you reaches that limit you might need to use multidex. Personally I decided to reduce the amount of libraries imported as some of them weren't really used or necesary. 
For further understanding of multidex you should read this,

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 16):

**3 Simple Steps:**

Step#1:
Multidexing is a new feature and so requires a support library to be compatible with pre-lollipop devices. You need to add the following to your gradle file dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Step#2:
Also enable multidex output in your gradle file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
   }
}
```

Step#3:
And then add the multidex support application to your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

**Note:** If your app already uses(extends) the Application class, you can override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex. For more information, see the MultiDexApplication reference documentation.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(context);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Here are the same instructions for reference: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html