# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils;

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in `Android 5.1.1` but I got running well on `6.0.1`

Here is the **class which have the error:**

```
public class DuelsTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    int fontType;

    public DuelsTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public DuelsTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public DuelsTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public void init(AttributeSet attrs) {

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DuelsTextView);
            fontType = a.getInteger(R.styleable.DuelsTextView_font_type, 0);
        }

        try {

            Typeface myTypeface = null;

            if (fontType == 0) {
                myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/BreeSerif-Regular.ttf");
            } else if (fontType == 1) {
                myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/MarkoOne-Regular.ttf");
            }

            this.setTypeface(myTypeface);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adamvarhegyi.duelsofcodrer"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1')

    compile('com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4')
    compile('de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0')
}
```

If I change the extending to simple `TextView` it's working fine, however **android studio suggests** me that I would have to use `AppCompatTextView` for custom views.

Why is this happening? What should I modify?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the **instant run** option and then running the app?

Comment: @Mandy8055 I don't use instant run at all.

Comment: Why are you having  `exclude module: 'support-v4'` ? Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39354357/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-running-app-with-android-5-1-with-android-st) question maybe this is same for you

Comment: can you please post the whole error log?

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that excluding a v4 library would have something to do with the v4 class not being found.

Comment: @TinTran It was there by default when I have created the project from Android Studio project examples.

Comment: You mean the `Android Studio project templates` right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change **these** dependencies

```
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1')
```

**to**

```
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0') 

compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0')
```

Don't know why you exclude v4, but if it's not for some reason I would keep it.

Don't know why its happening, but It happened to me recently and a fix was to match `buildToolsVersion` with support libraries version.

Comment: Compile SDK version has to match major version of support libs. As for build tools version, use the latest (26.0.1 as of August 19, 2017).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is related to using an older support library or by excluding the `support-v4` module. Also, the `compile` configuration is now [deprecated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ll-rkLCtyk&feature=youtu.be&t=29m18s) and should be replaced by `implementation` or `api`.

Your final gradle configuration should look like this,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
```

Finally, make sure to test once again with/without excluding the `support-v4`module.